# Sync between two servers behind seperate VPNs

Tags: ssh, vpn, rsync

Trying to rsync between two servers that are behind separate VPNs, so:

Server1 <-> VPN1 <-> INTERNET <-> VPN2 <-> Server2

Is there a relatively straight forward way to accomplish this?

Comment: I hate to say it like this, but if you have to ask, it is a little too compülex for you. This is mostly based on this being actually extremely trivial - but your list even misses the central VPN hub. So, no, for you that likely is too complex. Lack of fundamental knowledge. Hire an admin.

Answer (score 0):

If both servers face internet, this means each end has a public ip address, so basically you have rsync to the other side's public ip address.

The tunnel takes care of routing the packets:

source(private ip) ====> target (public ip)----vpn tunnel --->target(private ip)

Should look like this:

```
rsync -avuz source_directory user@target_public_ip:target_directory
```